# Cross-compiling Rust from Windows to ARM Linux

Tags: windows, gcc, arm, rust, cross-compiling

I'm using Windows 10. I would like to cross-compile a Rust program to run on `armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`. (`armv7-unknown-linux-muscl` would also be acceptable but it doesn't seem to be available.)

Here are my steps:

1. Install `rustup`
2. `rustup toolchain install stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`
3. `rustup toolchain default stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`
4. `rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`
5. Edit my `./cargo/config` file to contain:

   ```
   [build]
   target = "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf"
   ```
6. `cargo build`

This compiles everything fine, but when it comes to linking it gives this error:

```
error: could not exec the linker `cc`: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)
```

As far as I have been able to determine, this is because Rust doesn't have its own linker and uses GCC instead. Apparently I need to provide this myself and add this to the `./cargo/config` file:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "c:/path/to/my/gcc/cross/compiler"
```

Is that right? If so where on Earth can I download such a cross-compiler for Windows and why doesn't `rustup` install it? Having to compile a cross-compiling version of GCC yourself is the biggest pain of cross-compiling C/C++ programs. Does Rustup really not make this any easier?

Comment: Performing an internet search for `arm cross compiler windows` seems to have a number of promising leads that allow you to download a pre-built compiler to use as a linker. What question are you trying to ask here? If it's a feature request for rustup, perhaps make one on the repo? There's [some chatter about semi-related aspects](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/486).

Comment: Most of the results are for the embedded bare metal ARM GCC which is easily available in binary form [here](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded). That is `arm-none-eabi-gcc` (or something; these target triples are very arbitrary).

Comment: For a genericly packaged cross-toolchain, I'd go for the [Linaro toolchain binaries](http://www.linaro.org/downloads/). In case it's not clear, you'd want the i686_mingw32 one.

Comment: Aha! I had to [unzip it as admin](http://superuser.com/a/1076531/80582) for some reason, but after that it worked. Thanks for the mingw32 hint by the way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @Notlikethat's comment:

a) Yes you need to provide your own GCC cross-compiler.

b) You can get one [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5/arm-linux-gnueabihf/) (select a `mingw32` build).

Just unzip linaro's GCC then point cargo to it:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "C:/Users/me/gcc-linaro-5.3.1-2016.05-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.exe"
```

It seems to work even though it is `arm-` and not `armv7-`. I guess linking doesn't depend on the ISA. Actually I haven't run it yet, but it builds without errors!

**Edit:**

You can now use `armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf` instead and get an actually portable binary (i.e. it doesn't depend on the GNU C library which often causes compatibility issues).

Comment: Linking does depend on the ISA to an extent, but mostly in terms of floating-point stuff and general architecture profile (i.e. A vs. M). It also happens that the non-bare-metal Linaro builds are configured with ARMv7 (specifically Cortex-A9) as the default target anyway.

Comment: Ah that's convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For MacOS better use: `musleabihf`, for Windows you can use `gnueabihf` as bellow:

**Mac**

```sh
$ brew install arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils
$ rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf
```

In `.cargo/config`

```
[build]
target = "armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf"
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-c]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld"
```

With simple `src/main.rs`

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Raspberry!");
}
```

Then things are fine:

```sh
Hasans-Air:rpi hasan$ cargo build
   Compiling rpi v0.1.0 (/Users/hasan/PycharmProjects/rpi)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.41s
Hasans-Air:rpi hasan$ scp target/armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf/debug/rpi pi@192.168.1.43:
pi@192.168.1.43's password: 
rpi                                                                                         100% 2702KB   2.6MB/s   00:01    
Hasans-Air:rpi hasan$ ssh pi@192.168.1.43 'chmod +x ~/rpi && ~/rpi'
pi@192.168.1.43's password: 
Hello, Raspberry!
```

**Win 10**
 Get the linker from [here](https://gnutoolchains.com/raspberry/), and run:

```sh
rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Creating file  `.cargo/config`  with content:

```
[build]
target = "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf"

[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```

And with simple `src/main.rs`:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, Raspberry! from Win 10");
}
```

I was able to get things done

[image]

[image]